# Automatically expand C# 3 syntactic sugar

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Hello I'm in trouble with SlimDX samples, which just pretend to support VS 2005. Well there are VS2005 solution/project files but source code itself contains C# 3.0 new language features (mostly automatic properties). It would be hell to convert this stuff to C# 2.0 by hand. Is there any tool, which does it automatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know that the freely available [CodeRush Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/dd218053.aspx) does this, as I've already used it. The function is called "Create Backing Store". There are also other refactorings in there, I'm sure that converting to/from inferred types ('var') is also possible.

Comment: thanks, but I'm unable to get CodeRush Express working in VS 2005. It installed normally, but I don't see it anywhere in VS. Thanks for help.

Comment: True, it's not like it's in the menu's or anything, but if you place your cursor on an automatic property, you should see a blue underscore (similar to the red underscore). Also, hitting the key ctrl+` should show you CodeRush'es refactoring menu.

Comment: False, because I had to repair DXCore package, which finally integrated into VS. Stupid installer...

Answer (score 1):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) will certainly convert automatic properties to properties with a backing field with a couple of clicks.

It will also process a batch of files based on standards that you define so you might be able to get it to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling sources with C# 3.0 compiler and then use Reflector + [FileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) to dump decompiled sources to C# 2.0-compatible files.